# What Amazon CloudFormation template to use for asp.net?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I use the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio to deploy a CloudFormation stack. I have to create a stack template file or choose a sample template.

Which sample template suits asp.net ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AWS CloudFormation Sample Templates](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) recently gained dedicated Microsoft Windows Server templates, amongst these the [Windows_Roles_And_Features.template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/Windows_Roles_And_Features.template), which is a fairly generic one to *Create a single server specifying server roles running on Microsoft Windows Server® 2008 R2*.

If you inspect the template, you'll see all roles and features available for selection during stack creation/deployment:

> **Roles**: A SPACE seperated list of roles that you want to enable on this instance. Valid values are AD-Certificate, AD-Domain-Services, ADLDS, DHCP, DNS, Fax, File-Services, NPAS,
>   Print-Services, Web-Server, and WDS. [...]
>
> **Features**:  A SPACE seperated list of features that you want to enable on this instance. Valid values are NET-Framework, BITS,
>   BitLocker, BranchCache, CMAK, Desktop-Experience, DAMC,
>   Failover-Clustering, GPMC, Ink-Handwriting, Internet-Print-Client,
>   ISNS, LPR-Port-Monitor, MSMQ, Multipath-IO, NLB, PNRP, qWave,
>   Remote-Assistance, RDC, RPC-over-HTTP-Proxy, Simple-TCPIP,
>   SMTP-Server, SNMP-Services, Storage-Mgr-SANS, Subsystem-UNIX-Apps,
>   Telnet-Client, Telnet-Server, TFTP-Client, Biometric-Framework,
>   Windows-Internal-DB, PowerShell-ISE, Backup-Features, Migration, WSRM,
>   TIFF-IFilter, WinRM-IIS-Ext, WINS-Server, Wireless-Networking, and
>   XPS-Viewer. [...]

That should be all you need to pick and go - good luck!

Comment: Thank you steffen.What i want is to deploy a websites into multiple instance(three instances +laod balancing ).What are the roles?do you have a doc link?it's not security groups?

Comment: "error creating stack requires capabilities [capability_iam]" i try to create the stack but it displays this message.

Comment: I'm afraid the [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/) (surprisingly) still lacks support for the `CAPABILITY_IAM` flag - it should offer a checkbox like the AWS Management Console (_I acknowledge that this template may create IAM resources_); this is a security measure to ensure you _trust the source of the template since IAM resources [...] control access to your AWS resources_, see [Controlling User Access With AWS Identity and Access Management](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html) for details.